# Transforming varchar to date , to_date and to_datetime not working

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to transform a varchar to date 'YYYY-MM-DD' format

I try to_date and to_datetime and doesnt work.

The column of the dataframe looks like this

```
 meta_date 
1572776368
1572776368
1572776368
1572776369
1572776370
1572776373
1572776374
1572776386
1572776392
1572776400
1572776409
1572776409
1572776416
```

I try `select to_date(meta_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') from df` and `select to_datetime(meta_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') from df`

errors are: `function to_date(character varying) does not exist` and `function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist`

Comment: Is this sql server or postgresql? They are not the same thing. But those string values do not look like dates. They look like epoch dates. But the big question is why are you storing dates as string in the first place?

Comment: And even if you desire to store those values in a column that is not defined using the date datatype, why store them as strings when they CLEARLY are numbers.

Comment: Not really know how its being store, u believe it is a epoch value?

Comment: Your errormessages cannot be the results of your given selects. They say some functions with only one parameter do not exist but you are calling them with two! Try using ```select *, to_timestamp(meta_date::float8) from df```